# What is the full list of log entries in Anno 2070?

Tags: achievements, anno-2070

In Anno 2070, you can collect "log entries", small hints and tips for new players. When you have collected all of them, you get a secret achievement "Training Completed".

However, I cannot find a full list of log entries (and directions on how to get them) anywhere, not even on the Anno 2070 wiki.

Does anyone have all the log entries (and optionally the achievement) and cares to list them?

Comment: I'm sorry but asking for a list is not permitted as written in the [FAQ].

Comment: You can ask for a list, we just don't tend to like questions where every answer is a unique solution that is equally valid.  (For instance, "what games feature this game mechanic?").  They tend to take the form of "list of X." This question, however, is fine.

Comment: By the way, the list can be found here: http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/Data_log But the achievement can be impossible to get under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Lars Ebert in the comments, all the data entries are found on [this page](http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/Data_log) on the Anno 2070 wiki. The entries are all sorted in different categories and collecting them all will award the *Training Complete* achievement (or not, apparently it's impossible to get it after having the Deep Ocean Expansion).

The entries are as follows:

#### Command Centre (8 entries):

- Player Profile
- Message archive and data log
- Types of assignment
- Define Game parameters
- Participation in World events
- Methods of communication
- The Domination Conflict
- To stage a Domination Conflict

#### Game World (7 entries):

- The Ark
- Explore
- Ecobalance
- Islands
- Underwater world
- Life under water
- Disasters

#### Urban Development (11 entries):

- Island colonization
- Needs
- Building materials
- Public buildings
- Population groups
- Taxes
- Population needs
- Influence radii of Buildings
- Building types and attributes
- Level increase for population
- Media influence

#### Economy (13 entries):

- Production
- Logistics
- Plant productivity
- Energy
- Trade
- Debt
- Expanding Production areas
- Storage
- Increasing central Warehouse capacity
- Trading routes
- The Harbor
- The Energy transmitter
- Island shares

#### Vehicles (6 entries):

- Controlling Vehicles
- Ships
- Submarines
- Aircraft
- Reduced Vehicle speeds
- Replacement Vehicle

#### Diplomacy (8 entries):

- Contact
- Diplomatic status
- Agreements with neighbors
- Actions with diplomatic consequences
- War
- Quests
- Ultimatums
- Friendly turns

#### Items (2 entries):

- Items
- Researching your own Items