# How to get the "offline mode" log entry in Anno 2070?

Tags: achievements, anno-2070

In Anno 2070, you can collect "log entries", small hints and tips for new players.

I know one exists for "offline mode", but I am unable to get it (I tried playing offline for a bit, but didn't get it). What exact steps have to be performed to get that entry?

The reason I want it because of the "Training Completed" secret achievement, which you get when you discover all log entries ([also see my related question about all log entries](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80288/what-is-the-full-list-of-log-entries-in-anno-2070)). For those interested, there is a bug where you do not get the achievement if this is your last log entry, so you'd want to get it before your last one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't get this when my internet went out and I was forced into an offline mode...  Nope, I don't appear to have this log entry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is currently impossible to get this log entry. As far as I understood, the data log is not fully functional in offline mode, so you are unable to get the "offline mode" log entry. Therefore, it's also impossible to get the achievement "Training Completed" at the moment.

From what I gathered, the developers are aware of this problem, and might patch it in a future update or expansion, but nothing's been confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible even with addon - just found a workaround :D - I hibernated the PC with anno on (while playing continuous game) - after waking it up, i got in the game and i got the archievement after few secs of play.